# Why isn't Fourier Series taught in calculus 2?

Tags: calculus, fourier-series, self-learning

I am self taught and have read the book "Essential Calculus ETF" by Larson and Hosteller from cover to cover and have since been evaluating the more difficult problems in calculus. During my venture in solving difficult integrals using series expansions via the monotone convergence theorem, I noticed that some integrals were tackled easily with the Fourier series.

Now, why isn't this topic included in the same sections where power, taylor and maclaurin series are being discussed?

Not that I'm complaining (though I
favor maclaurin and this is my hobby, so I'm learning something new), but shouldn't this series also be included in Calculus 2?

Comment: I have seen it taught in calculus 2, just after Taylor series, for obvious reasons. Of course, the motivation is somewhat lacking and it certainly isn't rigorous

Comment: I deleted my comment as my answer most likely is not applicable to the region of the OP. Calculus 2 is clearly not the same course everywhere!

Comment: Maybe because Fourier series are _completely_ different things than Taylor or maclaurin series and the kind of analysis which goes into their study is much more involved than the one which goes into Taylor series.

Comment: @Shalop At graduate level, yes, but Dirichlet's theorem is not that difficult, and basic computations with Fourier series involve only some knowledge of series of functions.

Comment: @Shalop but at a very surface level, one can describe fourier series and taylor series in a conceptually similar way. Namely, approximating a some arbitrary (but of course, "nice enough") function by functions we are familiar with from grade school. Of course theis misses a ton of nuance, but i think it can be successful

Comment: @qbert Anyway, a Taylor series applied to $z=e^{i\theta}$ is basically a trigonometric series.

Comment: Any attempt at teaching Fourier series in calc 2 would be completely superficial. It would necessarily ignore the core concepts like orthogonality, applications to ODE and PDE, as well as key conceptual ideas like: how is regularity of a function related to decay of its coefficients? Also convolutions, integral kernels and approximation, and so much more. It is naive to say that Fourier series can be absorbed into power series because "$z=e^{ix}$." Power series are trivial in comparison, since you have convergence on an interval, and infinite differentiability there. If only Fourier had that.

Comment: @Shalop I know that. It's only to show that they start from ismilar concepts (they are only series). And even if it's only to prove $\sum_n 1/n^2=\pi^2/6$, it's already a nice achievement at this level (though there are some easier ways to this one). Of course the idea is not to jump into the more difficult details. However, when one teaches integration in high school, it's not Lebesgue either: I don't see the problem in teaching entry level material at entry level of curriculum.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut here in the us, there are already quite a lot of topics in calc 2 (integration, sequences, series, Taylor expansions) that many students already do quite poorly and there isn't much room for more topics anyways. You certainly have a point here, but I do prefer quality over quantity.

Comment: The name literally says four-year series... you don't just teach it in year 2...

Comment: @Mehrdad puns!!

Comment: I plan to teach it in my Calculus II class tomorrow (if there are not too many homework questions) !

Comment: About 5 years later and now I'm fully in software development! Ahh how I miss those days when I had full blown excuse to study some maths...may your student fair well!

Answer (score 10):

The primary use for Fourier series is solving second order differential equations which is not typically taught in Calculus II.  Also the basic theory behind Fourier series is infinite dimensional vector spaces, certainly not taught in Calculus II!

Comment: *“Also the basic theory behind Fourier series is infinite dimensional vector spaces”*  From a pure maths perspective that’s true, but you can teach/learn plenty of the main techniques/applications of Fourier series without any mention of any kind of vector spaces, so this isn’t really relevant to why they’re not taught in basic courses.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure what you mean by *"Calculus 2"*, so here is a tentative answer.

For comparison, in France Fourier series are typically taught (at a basic level, up to [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_conditions) and [Parseval's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem), in the second year of university. Taylor series are taught in first year (that would be, I *guess*, the first year of undergraduate studies in the United States). Differential equations are taught in first year (mainly through computation of solution of specific equations), while the general theorems ([Cauchy-Lipschitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) and similar) and series solutions ([Frobenius method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method)) are taught in second year. One would usually learn topology and the Lebesgue integral in third year (there is *some* topology before, but it's not even an overview, just the basic vocabulary).

The course on Fourier series is rather short compared to what is done on sequences and series of functions. They are both an application of series of functions, and the occasion to see prehilbertian structure and orthogonality in infinite dimension (but it's not greatly emphasized). Exercises are mainly about applications to the computations of numeric series.

Another answer seems to suggest infinite dimensional spaces are out of the question. They are actually seen (though very lightly) already in first year with spaces of polynomials and spaces of functions. However, the emphasis in first year is arguably on finite dimensional vector spaces and applications to matrices and geometry.

Caveat emptor: this is from remembrance of my academic studies 20 years ago, the curriculum may have changed a bit, and a teacher may have a different opinion.

---

Since you seem to be talking about high school (or secondary school): in France there is nothing about Rolle's theorem or Taylor series in high school. Calculus is limited to the computation of some limits, derivatives, and the basics about integration (integration by parts, but no change of variable). Differential equations are limited to 1st or 2nd degree linear ODE with constant coefficients. There is also some geometry and analytic geometry (up to conics and the use of complex numbers in plane geometry, and the basic theorems of trigonometry). I'd say the high school curriculum is rather light, compared to what is taught in university.

---

Note: if there is a reference for an up-to-date comparison of math curricula across countries, I would be greatly interested.

Comment: i am afraid that i have not yet taken calculus in university, I only know what is covered in the book "Essential Calculus ETF; Larson, Hosteller", which covers from basic limits to the divergence theorem. I am now exploring and perfecting my techniques before moving onto "Advanced Calculus; Loomis, Sternberg" (i have started on this and it starts on the subject of inifnite dimensional vector spaces and the notion of polynomials as linear combinations, if im not mistaken). At my university we follow the curriculum set forth by the first book I mentioned. But i have no yet formally anything.

Comment: this august I'd formally take calculus (basic)

Comment: @SSBASE Interesting. Judging **only** by the headlines, ETF is roughly what is taught in 1st year of university, but from the content available on Amazon, it looks like it's taught at a secondary school level (but there is not Rolle or Taylor in high school in France). On the other hand, university teaching is much more "formalist", and more like Loomis & Sternberg, though parts of it would be taught later, probably in 3rd year.

Comment: ETF is not terribly rigorous and i have had to supplement my learning with other sources). I am from Puerto Rico and have had to take my education into my own hands due to the lack of education in the United States (and by extension my island, as it is a territory of USA). I truly have a love and fascination for mathematics...

Comment: @SSBASE You should get a hand on some good books of advanced calculus, with many exercises (with solutions, preferably). I had an habit back then to get a few books from 2 to 3 years ahead, to familiarize with the concepts beforehand, and to better see where what I learned was actually leading. More than 3 years ahead would be too difficult I think. If you like abstract concepts, I suggest a (not too difficult) book on topology, as it explains a lot on analysis (continuity, limits...).

Comment: I will! Thanks for this!

Answer (score 4):

Not that this is entirely new, but I'd like to put my $2-$cents in.

Like most of mathematics, you can learn the basics of any rich theory at any time. However, to truly understand something, and to see it's utility and purpose, you may need to understand other areas of mathematics.

Fourier series aren't discussed in Calculus II, because they would be unmotivated. Why exactly should $f(x)$ be representable as an infinite series of integrals, using sine and cosine? The answer lies in the fact that the integral is a useful way of defining an inner-product on a vector space of continuous functions. This is useful in that it allows you to define the  **angle** between two functions, and it allows you to associate a **length** to a function. The integrals you compute are giving you vector building blocks which approximate your function, but the **why** is because these variants of sine and cosine produce what is called an orthonormal basis (whatever that means).

Fourier series is a powerful tool, which would be difficult to convey without the language of linear algebra, which typically taught after Calculus II and before Differential Equations.

At my institution, we teach Fourier series right after vector calculus. When students have a sufficient understanding of linear algebra to understand why Fourier series should work.

Comment: very nice! Thank you, i very much like mathematics and solving difficult difficult calculus problems. I have recently started a book on advanced calculus that starts off with with notation, set theory and vector spaces. I am excited. I encountered the need to use the fourier series in order to evaluate the infinite sum of 1/n^4  as part of the technique of using series expansions for unorthodox integrals (that abide by the monotone convergence theorem), i was just so intrigued i feel like i am going down a rabbit hole!!!

Comment: I'm glad you appreciated the input. I was much like you, when I first encountered Fourier series. I was in Calc II I explored **anything** involving the integral. I thought it was a magical object at the time. I think you'll find that the more you know from other fields of mathematics, the more powerful the tools you know will become. I wish I had known about SE back then.

Comment: I agree, integrals are fascinating and require much more finesse than derivatives/partials. Thanks to the intricacies of integration i have also had to study Lebesgue integration (but only due to the technique of differentiating under the integral sign), though very superficially. My favorite and most challenging subject I think has been the method of Langrange Multipliers for optimization and definitely a few topics Vector Analysis have to be revisited. But for atleast the start of the summer, I'd like to perfect my single variable techniques.

Comment: topics from* Vector Analysis

Comment: Lagrange multipliers, too, are deeply connected to topics in linear algebra. I believe you'll enjoy the study of the topic thoroughly.